# delay css from firing using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to delay css from firing using jquery?

I have some css which displays the menu on hover of an li but its really fast and i would like to delay it by 1 second or so.

I know i can do stuff like:

```
$('div#new-menu-lower ul li:hover ul li:first-child ul')
  .delay(800)
  .queue( function(next){ 
    $(this).css('display','block'); 
    next(); 
  });
```

But is there a way to keep the css and use JQ/JS to delay the css class from loading that would be better?

Comment: Side note: Why do you have an element with an ID of `div`? That's not fantastic naming strategy.

Comment: mistake................................

Comment: You want to delay the application of the CSS, and it seems from what you posted you're already doing that. What did I miss? :)

Comment: yes but the mark up is wrong? I am looking for alternative methods to do this? CSS3 transition-delay maybe?

Comment: What do you mean by `keep the css`? Keep it separated -- i.e. defined in a CSS-file parted from the Javscript?.

Comment: i dont want to define the css via jquery. I want jquery to say essentially delay when the css is read on hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way. If you keep your CSS in an external file, reference that through the `link`tag, then just after disabling the tag element, the DOM will stop referring the elements in the CSS. Then once u want to refer the elements, u can just enable the element.